# jvectormap show labels only for specific regions

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I'm trying to show labels for the only region I highlight on the map.

Here is the code:

```
var map = $('#map').vectorMap({
    regionsSelectable: true,
    regionsSelectableOne: true,
    series: {
        regions: [{
            scale: ['#cccccc', '#0A6EB4'],
            values: data
        }]
    },
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#ffffff',
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: '#cccccc',
            "stroke-width": 0,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
        hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        selected: {
            fill: '#0A6EB4'
        },
        selectedHover: {
            fill: '#1E4669'
        }
    },
    regionLabelStyle: {
        initial: {
            'font-family': 'Verdana',
            'font-size': '12',
            'font-weight': 'bold',
            cursor: 'default',
            fill: 'black'
        },
        hover: {
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    },
    labels: {
        regions: {
            render: function (code) {
                if (activeCountries.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
                    var regions = $("#map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject").regions;
                    console.log(code, regions[code]); //<< ERROR!
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the labels.regions.render function I'm able to get the code of the country, I'm able to verify that is a country present in the array activeCountries, but then when I try to retrieve the country name (regions[code].config.name) the regions[code] is undefined, the specific code is missing!

So I can show the labels on the regions that are present in the activeCountries array?

That is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The above image is done using Highmaps.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to deblocker that has found the solution.

Now I need only to find a way to add a white shadow to the region text to make it better visible also on dark highlighted regions.

Comment: unfortunately jVectorMap is not able to do it, so the only way is to change the component with something more professional and better developed, like highmaps or something else

Comment: hi Giox, did You see my update?

Comment: I added also the CSS for the `text-shadow`. You can easily adjust the shadow offset inside the chrome developer tool, until You get the desired effect. Just click the small square near the style declaration.

Comment: @deblocker you're my hero! Thanks man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I believe You are using a world map, is that correct?

Some countries are really too small to draw a SVG path in a meaningful way on a world map.

You can either:

- Use a map with a higher resolution (and obviously zoom-in until You see that tiny regions)
- Add markers to easily locate that small countries:

  ```
  {
    "BH": {"latLng": [26.066700, 50.557700], "name": "Bahrain"},
    "GI": {"latLng": [36.140751, -5.353585], "name": "Gibraltar"},
    "HK": {"latLng": [22.284681,114.158177], "name": "Hong Kong"},
    "MQ": {"latLng": [14.641528,-61.024174], "name": "Martinique"},
    "MT": {"latLng": [35.937496, 14.375416], "name": "Malta"},
    "MU": {"latLng": [-20.183590,57.941208], "name": "Mauritius"},
    "SG": {"latLng": [1.352083, 103.819836], "name": "Singapore"},
    "GP": {"latLng": [16.265000,-61.551000], "name": "Guadeloupe"}
  }
  ```

---

If You need the region names for the regions in the map, You can get it from the loaded maps:

> Here is the **DEMO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var map = "world_mill_en",
      regions = {"MN": "#fad"};
  $("#map").vectorMap({
    map: map,
    series: {
      regions: [{
        values: regions,
        attribute: "fill"
      }]
    },
    labels: {
      regions: {
        render: function(code){
          return regions[code] && jvm.Map.maps[map].paths[code].name;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap Labels</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    .jvectormap-region.jvectormap-element {
      text-shadow: -1px -1px 3px #fff, 1px -1px 3px #fff, -1px 1px 3px #fff, 1px 1px 3px #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap@2.0.4/tests/assets/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

BTW, thanks to [bjornd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367960/bjornd) for the great jVectorMap.